# Dimension mismatch between header row and first data row. Bigmatrix

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I'm working with large data sets. I can read some of them with the `read.table` command but using the argument `fill=TRUE` due to such data sets have some blanks which represent NA's.

Now, I have a Database up to 35 Gb so the usual `read.table` command is useless, so I found the read.big.matrix function into the `bigmemory` package. The issue is that it returns the following error:

> "Dimension mismatch between header row and first data row." I think it is because it is not reading the blanks as NA's.

Do you know how can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You could test this theory using a smaller file, say the first 10 or 50 rows of your dataset.

Comment: @lmo Thanks. With read.table I can use the argument nrows to do what you suggest, do you know which is the similar argument for read.big.matrix?

Comment: I checked and it doesn't seem like there is a similar argument to `read.big.matrix`. Are you using Linux? If so, you could try something like `head -50 filename > tempFile`. I think that would work, but double check just to be safe.

Comment: can you provide an example that we could use to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. I found the solution finally, use `head = FALSE` with read.big.matrix function. This works for me but first row of result big.matrix has NA for all columns, because it can't convert colnames to integer type(if you have selected integer as type of big.matrix).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this old question, I recently figured out that for a `file` like this:

```
somethin rowname1 rowname2
colname1 value1.1 value1.2
colname2 value2.1 value2.2
```

If you use the `header = TRUE` and `has.row.names = TRUE` arguments to load the file in R with `read.big.matrix`, it won't work because the function expects the `somethin` field to actually not exist. Since you didn't provide your exact command I don't know if this was the problem here, but basically the function checks that the header has the same number of fields as the first row of the actual data, however when you specify the first column as row names then the first row of data has one less field and the header should match this number of fields. You may delete the `somethin` field using linux commands like `cat <(head -1 file | cut -d' ' -f2-) <(tail -n+2 file) > newFile`